# Unity Designers may only attach my script to a terrain object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way I can prevent the designer from attaching my script to anything except a terrain type?

Normally when I create a script/Component/MonoBehavior, Unity allows a designer to add it to any game object.  How do I limit that?

Comment: You'll probably have better luck asking this here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity

Comment: I just posted this question on the other site as well:  http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/87730/a-script-that-can-only-be-attached-to-a-terrain.  If one is answered, I'll post the result on both.

Comment: (To whomever voted this down, could you please include why?  If you think this *should* be expressed differently, please suggest what I can do better.  Thanks)

Comment: Please don't cross post your questions. It's bad form. I suggest you remove this one.

Comment: @Byte56, StackOverflow does not allow me to delete this.  - per sf:  "Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two methods come to mind, but none are very elegant.

1) Implement `OnValidate()`. The downside is that's it's called only when modifying component's values, or entering/exiting game mode.

```
void OnValidate() {
    if (GetComponent<Terrain>() == null) {
        Debug.LogError("You can't attach this component without terrain!");
        DestroyImmediate(this);
    }
}
```

2) Make the script run in the editor, and implement `OnAwake()`. But be aware that methods like `Update()` will be called in the editor.

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
class MyScript: MonoBehaviour {
    void OnAwake() {
        if (GetComponent<Terrain>() == null) {
            Debug.LogError("You can't attach this component without terrain!");
            DestroyImmediate(this);
        }
    }
}
```